# uniform distribution: expectation of sum squared observations

Tags: self-study, variance, sample, uniform-distribution

I'm trying to follow [ML lesson about Bayesian inference](http://ml-tau-2015.wdfiles.com/local--files/course-schedule/ML-lesson-2.pdf). 
They have a sample of n observations from a uniform distribution: $x_i = U(0, \theta)$.

They claim that $E[(\sum x_i)^2] = n(n-1)\theta^2/4 + n \theta^2/3$ - why is that true?

I tried by myself and got a different result, where did I go wrong?:

$Var(x_i) = \theta^2/12 = E(x_i^2)-E^2(x_i);$

$E(x_i^2) = \theta^2/12 + (\theta/2)^2 = \theta^2/3$

$E[(\sum x_i)^2] = n\theta^2/3$

Where did the first term come from??

Comment: You forgot the covariance terms, i.e. $E[x_ix_j]$.

Comment: @AlexR. oops, they are independent.

Comment: It is not because they are independent that $\mathbb{E}[X_iX_j]=0$.

Comment: $E[X_i]=\theta/2$...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{eqnarray*}
\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}\right)^{2}&=&\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}^{2 }+2\sum_{i<j}^{n}x_{i}x_{j}\\
E\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}\right)^{2}&=&\sum_{i=1}^{n}E\left(x_{i}^{2 }\right)+2\sum_{i<j}^{n}E\left(x_{i}x_{j}\right)\\
&=&\dfrac{n\theta^{2}}{3}+2\dfrac{n(n-1)}{2}\left[Cov\left(x_{i}x_{j}\right)+E(x_i)E(x_j)\right]\\
&=&\dfrac{n\theta^{2}}{3}+2\dfrac{n(n-1)}{2}\left[0+\dfrac{\theta}{2}\dfrac{\theta}{2}\right]\\
E\left(\sum_{i=1}^{n}x_{i}\right)^{2}&=&\dfrac{n\theta^{2}}{3}+\dfrac{n(n-1)\theta^{2}}{4}
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: thanks, but the first term should be $\frac{n\theta^2}{3}$ and not $\frac{n\theta^2}{2}$

Comment: also the second term could be simply $\sum_{i \neq j}$, why do we divide by 2 and then multiply by 2?

Comment: @ihadanny, Sorry, there was a typo.  Note that $x_{i}x_{j}=x_{j}x_{i}$, and there are $n(n-1)/2$ such pairs. $ \sum_{i\neq j} = 2\sum_{i<j}$.

Comment: got it! I was suggesting that you could write it more simply as $\sum_{i \neq j}$ and there are $n(n-1)$ such pairs - but we're saying the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simple re-arrangement of the variance formula
$$var (Y)=E (Y^2)-[E (Y)]^2$$
Set $Y=\sum_ix_i $ and you have:
$$E [(\sum_ix_i)^2]=var [\sum_ix_i]+[E (\sum_ix_i)]^2$$

Comment: ha :) thanks but that's exactly what I did - and it's not the correct answer... please re-read the question...

Comment: @ihadanny - actually, you didn't apply this formula.  The first term is $n\theta^2/12$ and the second term is $(n\theta/2)^2$.  Add them together and you have $n\theta^2 (n/4+1/12)=n\theta^2 ((n-1)/4+1/3) $.

Comment: oops. you're right - I wasn't careful with the $n$s in my derivation. thanks.